# Wave and superposition.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose we have the complex wave function : 
\begin{equation*}
f(z,t)=Ae^{i\left( kz -\omega t\right)}
\end{equation*}
So i read in a book that

"Any wave can be expressed as a linear combination of sinusoidal ":
\begin{equation*}
f(z,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} A(k)e^{ikz-i\omega t}dk
\end{equation*}
But it doesn't provide details or a proof about that .
Sorry if this topic is not very relevant to pure mathematics but i want to see a formal proof about that, where can i find it ? I suppose that is related to fourier ( transform).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform). What looks confusing to you?

Comment: In the first form we have the plane wave and in the second formula there is no only the part $ A\exp \left( ikx -i\omega t \right)$ but but and the integral so why is this obvious ?.

Comment: Whats is the wave general equation.?

Comment: $u_{tt} =c u_{xx}$

Comment: Has it asolution.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding here is that if $f$ and $g$ are solutions of the wave equation

$$u_{tt}=cu_{xx},$$

then $f(x,t)+g(x,t)$ is also a solution. In physics this is known as [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle).

Now, your integral is a Fourier transform of a particular solution. You can see that it only has plane waves in the integrand (the solutions of the form of your first formula), modulated by a $k$-dependent function $A$. This just uses the continuous superposition of plane waves with all $k\in\mathbb R$ taken with different amplitudes given by $A$.

Given nice enough $A$, you can verify that the integral does indeed satisfy the wave equation.

To get back the wave function of

$$f(x,t)=Ce^{i(kx-\omega t)},$$

you can set $A$ in the Fourier integral to

$$A(\kappa)=C\delta(\kappa-k),$$

where $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).

Comment: Sorry but i think there is a misunderstanding , just to clarify that , i didn't say that $f(z,t)$ is a solution of the wave equation i just said that it is a wave ... i should have rather wrote "plane wave" not "wave function".

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis but it does nonetheless solve the equation you mentioned in the comments. And the integral representation does work for your wave if you set $A(\kappa)\propto\delta(\kappa-k)$ where $\delta$ is [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Comment: So my question remains , what about a formal proof ? Where can i find a proof ? Do you know?

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis I don't quite get, proof of what you would like to see. That there exists $A$ such that your Fourier integral converges to your plane wave? Or of what?

Comment: Yes , that there exists A such that ...

Comment: Well, isn't constructive proof good enough? I've already proposed the form of $A(\kappa)$ which satisfies this.

Comment: I don't think is formal proof .. using dirac .. is not even a function

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis it's not a funciton, but it is a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). There's a solid theory of distributions, which does account for all relevant properties of Dirac delta.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55115/discussion-between-chaviaras-michalis-and-ruslan).